# how to make an Activity not to repeat its on create method continuosly when resumed

Tags: android

I have a list activity and I am populating data into the list from database. The problem is that when the activity resumed or when i open another clss from that class whithout finishig the list class or when the phone sleeps and if i open the phone the data inside the list repeat itself or populate again

Comment: Provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can create a Bundle to save your application state when the user leaves it. Then, on your onCreate, check if the Bundle isn't null, and if so just recover datas from last session. Please check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android lifecycle, onCreate is called whenever the app starts from "no state" - meaning that either the App was killed (after being sent to background and the OS ran out of RAM), was rotated or was started after a fresh boot.

There's not much you can do about that.